# Image not loaded in 30 seconds [Galleria]

Tags: jquery, galleria

I'm using Galleria to display dynamic image content, but I am experiencing this persistent error for every set of image that I try to display. The slide loaded correctly for a few moments, then it started to throw errors:
Image not loaded in 30 seconds: http://cache.daylife.com/imageserve/0bzV4V1gMJ5qG/45x45.jpg
This is the link for the thumbnail image, not the image url. I m not entirely sure what is causing the error. Thanks!

Comment: It's possibly caused by server response time, image size or both. We need more details to provide quality solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I just hid the error via:

```
    .galleria-errors
      {
          visibility:hidden;
          display:none;
      }
```

in my css file

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that has been fixed in the last version which has been released few days ago. Please download the latest version http://galleria.io/download/ and everything will work smooth :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, finally ended up switching to Colorbox http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/